# SQL 2012 Password Comparing always returning 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

Wondering if I can get a little help here with my query.

Table Structure

```
UserID    BigInt    Primary   Auto
UserName  VarChar(64)
UserPass  VarChar(Max)
UserHash  VarChar(Max)
```

Inserting the user

```
SET @HASH = ABS(CHECKSUM(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(32)));
SET @PW = 0x0200 + @HASH + HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', CAST(@UP AS VARBINARY(MAX)) + @HASH);

Insert Into [MY].[USERS_TABLE]
(UserName, UserPass, UserHash)
Values
(@UN, @PW, @HASH);
```

This all works as expected with the has stored, and the password stored encrypted with the hash

My issue is stemming from the selection of the user a.k.a. a Login

```
Declare @Hash   VarBinary(Max);
Declare @Pass   VarBinary(Max)
Set @Hash = (Select userHash From MY.USERS_TABLE Where UserName = @UN);
SET @Pass = 0x0200 + @Hash + HASHBYTES('SHA2_512', CAST(@UP AS VARBINARY(MAX)) + @Hash);

Select userID, PWDCOMPARE(@UP, @Hash) As PWCompared
From MY.USERS_TABLE
Where UserName = @UN
AND
UserPass = @Pass;
```

Now, this does work, however, I'd rather be using the PWDCOMPARE function instead of checking the @Pass against the UserPass column, but it always returns a 0

Yes, I am sure that the info I am passing to it is correct :)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In first snippet you store @HASH in UserHash column. So it holds the thing you are using as a salt I suspect ( ABS(CHECKSUM(CRYPT_GEN_RANDOM(32))) ).

Then in next snippet you set @Hash to that value in the UserHash column, then compare that using PWDCOMPARE. So you are comparing the wrong value in that function.

Also, the [PWDCOMPARE documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd822792.aspx) says the hash should be a varbinary(128).

Comment: I don't think you should use PWDCOMPARE. You're already creating the hash again, just do a direct compare (like you are doing in the final condition of your WHERE clause where you say 'UserPass = @Pass). The PWDCOMPARE is redundant and doesn't work because it is expecting something that is the output of HASHBYTES, probably expecting it to be unsalted to. Some similar work [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8503582/sql-server-alternative-implementation-of-pwdencrypt-and-pwdcompare).